# Find a mistake in the following bogus proof

Tags: trigonometry, fake-proofs

**Theorem:** The function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [-10,10]$ defined by $f(x) = \cos(x)+\sin(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has no maximum or minimum on ($-\infty,+\infty$)

**Proof:** The function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ so one should be able to find its extrema by setting the derivative to 0. In particular, $$(\sin(x)+\cos(x))' = 0$$
$$\cos(x)-\sin(x) = 0$$
$$\sin(x) = \cos(x)$$
$$\sin(x+\pi/2) = \sin(x)$$
$$x+\pi/2 = x.$$

And the final equation is never true.
Yet WolframAlpha disagrees with my conclusions...

Comment: Since $\sin$ isn't injective, you can't conclude $x = y$ from $\sin x = \sin y$.

Comment: Note that $\sin \pi=\sin 0=0$ and $\pi\ne 0.$

Comment: In particular, $\sin(\frac \pi 4+\frac \pi 2)=\sin(\frac \pi 4)$.

Comment: WolframAlpha has many reasons for that!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Yet WolframAlpha disagrees."  Are you saying WolframAlpha says $x + \pi/2 = x$?

Comment: lol, no I mean it disagrees about the function having no extrema (I had the function plotted)

Comment: It is a common early error to think of function application, like $\sin(x)$, as a kind of multiplication, and that we can "cancel." But that isn't the case. If $f(x)=x^2$, then $f(2)=f(-2)$, but $2\neq -2$. The temptation to think you can cancel is even stronger when you don't use parentheses - writing $\sin x$ instead of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: I was vaguely aware of the problem, but I thought it is an issue only when you have $\sin(x+2\pi)$. Now I see it is more general than that.

Comment: @CaveJohnson and this follows directly from the symmetries of the sine function.

Comment: just plot sin x and cos x on the same graph.

Comment: @DanielFischer Does that mean if two functions were injective then I can say $x = y$?

Comment: @JeelShah That's more or less the definition of injectivity. $f \colon A \to B$ is injective if (and only if) $\bigl(f(x) = f(y)\bigr) \implies (x = y)$ for all $x,y\in A$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right! Silly me. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Here is a variation:  $1\equiv 2 \mod 7$.  Their cubes are congruent, and we think of $f(x)=x^3$ as injective.  But injectivity over one domain (the real numbers) does not guarantee injectivity over another (the residues modulo $7$).

Comment: By the way, after fixing the mistake, you find that the maximum occurs at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and is equal to $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=(\cos \frac{\pi}{4})+(\sin \frac{\pi}{4})= \frac12\sqrt{2} + \frac12\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2} \approx 1.41$.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem is that 
$$
\sin(\pi/2 +x) = \sin(x)
$$
does not imply that
$$
x+\pi/2 = x.
$$
This would only be true if $\sin$ was one-to-one on the interval considered.

Answer (score 4):

**Theorem.** Any continuous and periodic function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ achieve their maximum and minimun values infinitely many times.

**Proof.** Assume that the period is $T>0.$ Now we consider $f:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$ the restriction of $f$ to $[0,T].$ Because of Weirstrass theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) there exist $c,d\in [0,T]$ such that $f(c)\le f(x)\le f(d),\forall x\in [0,T].$

Now, since $f$ is periodic we have that $f(c)\le f(x)\le f(d),\forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$ Moreover, note that $f(c+kT)=f(c),\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and  $f(d+kT)=f(d),\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}.$ QED.

Note $f(x) = \cos(x)+\sin(x)$ satisfies the hypothesis of the above theorem. So it satisfies the thesis.

The problem in your proof is that $\sin$ is not injective. So, from $\sin x=\sin y$ you can't conclude $x=y.$ Note that $\sin 0=\sin\pi=0$ and $0\ne \pi.$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\sin(x+\pi/2)=\sin(x)$ has solutions $\pi/4$ and $5\pi/4$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. More generally, it has solutions $\pi(n-7/4)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$.

From that equality you want to conclude that $x+\pi/2=x$, which has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cos (x)=sin (phi/2-x).
So compare both.
You get 2x=phi/2.
x=phi/4.
It has maximum value at phi/4.
Similarly at x=5phi/4 you get minimum.

Comment: $phi$ (the greek letter "phi") is different from the greek letter $\pi$ ("pi", in english speaking countries often pronounced "pie").

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the one outlined in [Thomas's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2008023/283563), there's another mistake in the proof. Consider a function $f(x) = x$ on $[-10; 10]$. It has $$f^\prime(x) = 1 \neq 0$$ everywhere, but it definitely has its maximum at $x=10$ endpoint and its minimum at $x=-10$ endpoint.

Comment: This is not an issue in the presented 'proof' above because the function is defined on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score -3):

The function is continuous and periodic, so by Bolzano Weierstrass it must have a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to point out that the above approach of setting the derivative equal to zero is not always the one you want to use

Comment: But the question isn't "how can I prove that this must have extreme points?"  The question is "What's wrong with this proof that there are no extreme points?"